# How do I cleanup my database with data that is no longer being used?

Tags: database

I am working with Advanced Custom Fields and I noticed that once I delete a field for a custom post type it will stay in the database. Is there a way that Wordpress can do a cleanup for everything that isn't being used? I read a little bit about cron jobs but to my understanding but I really couldn't see a way for a job to know what the site uses, it probably could only delete revisions of things. And that wouldn't solve the problem. I also think I could just uninstall the plugin and reinstall it. But that also isn't a realistic solution.

Comment: The easiest way in terms of "stress", "avoiding trouble", etc is' to use a plugin for this. Sure, you can search and delete stuff manually, but that is rather risky and not recommended for unexperienced users. In WordPress terms, you are looking for "transcient options", which are things like old options etc. Plugin examples: wp db cleaner or wp optimize, just to name two of them. Install wp db cleaner, delete transcient options - done.

Comment: Those plugins can’t reliably do this either. There is no way to tell, just by looking, what data in a WordPress database is being used. The only way is for somebody who knows to manually check.